# Power amplifier vs voltage amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, power-amplifier

I am trying to learn more about the different types of amplifiers.

I have built a voltage amplifier but I am trying to learn how to build a power amplifier and I don't understand the design differences between them.

When I try to look up a class A power amp and a class A voltage amp the circuit looks the same.

What are the design differences between a class A power amplifier and a class A voltage amplifier? What makes them different?

Comment: If a high resistor is in power path it is more probably going about signal (or low-power) amp.

Comment: This terminology is not universal. A power amplifier can also be a voltage amplifier designed to drive low impedances.

Comment: Marcus, just to add, the simple 1-quadrant class-A is what will be a voltage amplifier and separately 2-quadrant class-A. which are for power delivery.

Comment: Marcus, I should have added what I mean. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xKAy0.png) is what I mean. Both are Class-A stages. But one delivers power and has a voltage gain of about 1 and high current gain. The other delivers voltage amplification but not necessarily much current gain, usually only to higher impedance loads (greater than RC) where power delivery into their output load isn't the design goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that a class A amplifier can deliver power to something. The first case is when the "load" being powered is connected between the transistor's collector and the supply rail, and the second is when the load does not form part of the amplifier itself, and is an external, subsequent element.

#### Load between collector and supply

By "load", I mean whatever element is supposed to be receiving power from the amplifier. In this scenario, the load forms part of the amplifier itself, and is connected between the transistor's collector and the power supply. That is what is meant by "class A operation" in the strict sense of the term:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFRHLt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In these scenarios, the load always receives power according to whatever voltage is placed across it, and whatever resulting current flows through it:

$$ P = V \times I $$

Given that your choice of R2 determines voltage gain, or transconductance, this class A design always presents the intended voltage across the load, or passes the intended current through it. In this sense the amplifier is already a "power amplifier". It needs no additional "power stage" or "buffer", since it inherently delivers power to the load in the intended quantity, and what the load does with that power is not this amplifier's concern.

On the left we are powering a loudspeaker via an audio transformer. We wish to modulate the voltage across the transformer's primary winding, whose resistance we know to be 600Ω. As we would do for a regular class A voltage amplifier, we choose R2a to produce the required voltage gain \$A\$:

$$ A = \frac{600\Omega}{120\Omega} = 5 $$

That is, a signal of amplitude 1V peak-to-peak at Q1's base will produce a variation of voltage across the winding of 5V peak-to-peak:

[image]

The resulting current depends on the load's impedance, and delivered power will depend on both voltage across and current through it, but unless you connect something else to Q1's collector, that's where the story ends. Even though this circuit has voltage gain, which we designed to be 5, the load takes whatever current it takes, getting all the power it needs, and we can call this circuit a "power amplifier" already, with nothing else to add.

The right hand circuit aims to modulate LED current in proportion to a potential at Q2's base. This time, the LED decides its own voltage, which will remain more or less constant over a wide current range, meaning that collector potential will hardly change at all. Consequently voltage gain will be near zero! Here we are interested in how collector current changes with base potential, not collector voltage. Gain will be in units of amps-per-volt, not volts-per-volt, called "transconductance" \$G\$:

$$ G = \frac{1}{R_{2B}} = \frac{1}{120} = 8.3\frac{mA}{V}$$

Here's what happens to LED current, when a 1V peak-to-peak sinusoid is applied to Q2's base:

[image]

Once again, there's no "power stage" or "buffer" or other modification needed to transform this amplifier into a "power amplifier". It already delivers exactly the right power to the load, because it *already is* a power amplifier.

I reiterate that the load, in this case an LED, gets exactly the power that this class A amplifier is designed to deliver to it, and for this reason can say that this design *is already* a power amplifier.

This is not to say, though, that you can insert any old load there. The problem inherent to the class A design is that quiescent current (current passing through the load and the transistor when input is "quiet") is always substantial. Typically, when the collector is half-way between the positive and negative supplies (+6V in the above examples), current is also half-way between maximum and minimum. There's *always* current flowing, and always power wasted because of that.

If you connected an 8Ω speaker directly as the load (no transformer) in schematic above left, and adjusted R2a to suit, on average you'd have 6V across the loudspeaker, and the remaining 6V across the transistor, even with a quiescent input. Both transistor and speaker would pass current, and dissipate heat:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I = \frac{6V}{8\Omega} = 0.75A \\ \\
P_{Q1} = {P_{SPEAKER}} = 6V \times 0.75A = 4.5W \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Either you use components that can tolerate such conditions, or you use a different design.

#### Subsequent external load

Sometimes we use a class A amplifier as a simple voltage amplifier, and we take its output from the transistor collector. We replace the load from before with a simple resistance, which allows us to set voltage gain, and our signal of interest is now collector potential:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkLcVI.png)</sup>

<sub>Note: Voltage source V2 is used in this example to "bias" the system so that the output is centered (has a mean value) at 0V.</sub>

That's an amplifier that has a voltage gain of about \$\frac{R_1}{R_2}=5\$, subjected to two different loads. On the left there's no load at all. On the right, though, R3 is a "heavy" 1kΩ. They are still both class A amplifiers, but where we had a transformer/speaker or LED before, now we have a simple resistor R1. Power is delivered to R1, as you would expect, but that power now is wasted as heat, and unused. This is now a plain old voltage amplifier.

Whatever is connected to that output is going to draw some current from it, and an amplifier's ability to maintain its intended output voltage under that load is what differentiates it between "power amplifier" and just a regular voltage amplifier.

In other words, a voltage amplifier that deserves the title "power amplifier", is one that is is able to maintain its intended output voltage even under heavy load. It's still a voltage amplifier, but it is able to provide whatever current the load demands.

As an analogy, all cranes are supposed to be able to lift their load to a height of 1m. All cranes are cranes. However, some cranes can lift 10,000kg to that height, but some cranes will fail to lift even 100kg only 1mm off the ground. Not all cranes are "power" cranes.

For this amplifier to successfully maintain its output at 10V, even with that load present, then it must simultaneously provide the requisite current through R3, which by Ohm's law would be:

$$ I_{R3} = \frac{V_{R3}}{R_3} = \frac{10V}{1k\Omega} = 10mA $$

In the schematic above, that's clearly not the case, as ammeter AM1b shows. This is a good voltage amplifier with no load, but as soon as we demand any current from it, if fails to attain adequate output swing, and gain drops. It cannot be considered to be a power amplifier in any sense. Graphs of \$V_{IN}\$ (blue), \$V_{OUT1}\$ (orange) and \$V_{OUT2}\$ (tan) will illustrate:

[image]

The input signal \$V_{IN}\$ (blue) is 4V peak-to-peak, and we would expect an output of 5 times greater amplitude. That's not a problem for this amplifier when unloaded, as we can see \$V_{OUT1}\$ is 20V peak-to-peak, but the moment we add the 1kΩ load, our amplifier's output \$V_{OUT2}\$ (tan) is attenuated by 50%.

To reiterate, a power amplifier is a voltage amplifier that *is* able to meet the current demands of its load. This one cannot.

To turn this circuit into a power amplifier, not only must it have a voltage gain of 5, but also the ability to provide all the *current* that would be demanded by any reasonable load, such as an 8Ω loudspeaker.

If you wanted that ±10V signal to appear across an 8Ω speaker, then expect a commensurate demand for current:

$$ I_{OUT} = \frac{V_{OUT}}{R_{OUT}} = \frac{\pm 10V}{8\Omega} = \pm 1.25A $$

You must therefore endow your amplifier with the ability to produce at least +1.25A when its output is required to be +10V, and also −1.25A when the output should be −10V. The application may only call for positive output voltages (or only negative!), and so how you go about this depends on the application.

R1 and R2 both introduce resistance in the path from power supply rails to the eventual output, so its ability to source/sink current into and out of its output is "impeded" by them. Any such resistance in an amplifier's output path affects its ability to source and sink current to/from the load, and is called "output impedance". This particular design has an output impedance of many hundreds of ohms. With a load of 8Ω you need to aim for an output impedance of much less than that.

It's worth noting that it is of course possible to decrease a class A amplifier's output impedance simply by reducing R1 and R2, but the cost is greater quiescent current, and the improvement is only minor.

Usually we would add an additional "buffer" stage to the amplifier, able to reproduce the voltage output of the first stage, but with much greater ability to satisfy the load's current demands. In applications where output is of one polarity only, a simple emitter follower may be all that's needed. In audio system, it's usually achieved by a push-pull pair of emitter followers:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM0ixl.png)</sup>

Because the first stage has such high output impedance, we must avoid excessive loading there. Power stage 2 (the "buffer") must draw as little current as possible from stage 1. To achieve that, I've used two [darlington pairs](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/darlington-transistor.html), with extremely high current gain, to keep base current down to microamps, which you can see on ammeter AM2. This places such a small load on the first stage, that the signal at OUT1 is hardly affected at all.

The power stage has a voltage gain of about 1, so its role is solely to offload the first stage, and take on responsibility for current provision for the load. This can seen on ammeters AM2 and AM4. When the output is (nearly) 10V, the first stage is being asked to provide only a few tens of microamps. Contrast that with current in the 8Ω loudspeaker load, over 1A!

Note that all this load current is now being drawn not from the first stage power supply (which ammeter AM1 shows to be only a few milliamps), but rather from the supply to the power stage, which is visible on AM3.

Combined, these two stages form a "power amplifier with a voltage gain of 5".

This power stage is very flawed. Take a look at the graphs of \$V_{IN}\$, \$V_{OUT1}\$ and \$V_{OUT2}\$ over time:

[image]

Notice how the potential at OUT1 is now unaffected, because it's almost completely unloaded, and achieves full swing.

Notice also how the power stage output OUT2 has problems. Its amplitude is a couple of volts short of what we would like, and there are flats in the waveform. This is due to [crossover distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_distortion), a side effect of using emitter followers, which can be mitigated in many ways that I won't cover here.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a voltage amplifier and a power amplifier is what they are used for. A voltage amplifier is used to provide voltage gain to increase the amplitude of a signal, a power amplifier is used to drive power into a load.

The class of an amplifier depends on how the signal is amplified. Classes A through C are based on over what part of the signal the active devices are conducting. Other classes (D and up) deal with digital signals and specialized types of amplifiers.

A class A voltage amplifier and power amplifier can be very similar circuits, for example using vacuum tubes they may look like this:

[image: triode amplifiers]

In the one being used as a voltage amplifier the load is a 100k resistor, this will give a relatively high output voltage, but because the impedance is high there's not a lot of power, the circuit following it would need to have a high input impedance. In the one used as a power amplifier the load is a speaker and is transformer coupled to match the high plate impedance to the speaker's low impedance.

What would make them both class A is that both would be biased such that if you input a sine wave the tube would conduct through all 360\$^{\circ}\$ of the waveform.

Answer (score 1):

Some amps do not amplify voltage, but only current (and hence power). An example of such an amp is an emitter follower a/k/a common collector. The current gain of these amps can be quite high, but the voltage gain is never greater than 1.

On the opposite end of the spectrum is a common base amplifier. Such amplifiers have no current gain, but significant voltage gain.

In the middle are common emitter amplifiers which generally have both voltage and current gain.

All amplifiers are in one way or another *power* amplifiers. Power is voltage times current, so even if one of voltage or current is not amplified, the other is, so the result is that power is amplified.

However, if someone is *distinguishing* a power amplifier from a voltage amplifier, it may be because the "power" amplifier in question does not amplify voltage but only current (and hence power).

It should be noted that the common X amplifiers are often just *stages* in a multi-stage amplifier. So a common emitter stage might be followed by an emitter follower stage. Emitter follower stages in one form or another (for example push-pull amplifiers) are common as an *output* stage of an amplifier.

The common emitter/collector/base amplifiers are based upon Bipolar Junction Transistors (BJTs). There are also amplifiers based upon MOSFETs, known as common source/drain/gate amplifiers, which have similar but not identical characteristics. At audio frequencies, the gate of a MOSFET does not draw appreciable current, so the current gain of a common source or common drain amplifier is very high. But because the gate current is so small, typically it is not considered to be input of interest, but rather the input of interest is a *voltage*, even if the output of interest is a current. For such amplifiers, instead of speaking of current gain, one usually refers to the change in output current over the change in input voltage, or transconductance. This would be a useful parameter to characterize a common drain, a/k/a source follower amplifier.

> What are the design differences between a class A power amplifier and a class A voltage amplifier? What makes them different?

Typically, a class A amplifier refers to a common emitter amplifier (operated in neither saturation nor cut-off), which amplifies both voltage and current. This is why when you search for class A voltage amplifier and class A power amplifier, you get similar circuits.

> What is the best class of amplifier for amplifying current but not voltage?

The simplest amplifier to amplify current is a simple emitter follower. The one below is an AC coupled emitter follower, which is uses a few more components than the DC coupled version. It operates in class A (no clipping) when the peak-to-peak input voltage is 2V or less.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP2IJX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, the voltage gain is very close to 1.

[image]

But the current gain is quite high.

[image]

The disadvantages of this amplifier include low efficiency, and requiring a relatively high supply voltage relative to output voltage swing to prevent clipping.

Next is a class AB push-pull amplifier using a bipolar supply. It consists of two complementary emitter followers. It is DC coupled, and much more efficient than the previous circuit, but it has a problem which we will see shortly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhhEII.png)</sup>

The voltage gain is less than one, which is usually not a problem. However, it can be seen that there is cross-over distortion.

[image]

The current gain is again quite good.

[image]

To fix the cross-over distortion without introducing large "shoot through" currents requires extra care in the design. The following circuit attempts to match the Vbe voltage drops on the output voltage followers by using matching transistors to provide bias. There are other techniques for cancelling cross-over distortion that are perhaps better in one way or another. This circuit merely demonstrates that techniques are available to address cross-over distortion in push-pull amplifiers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fywlx4.png)</sup>

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the best class of amplifier for amplifying current but not voltage?

Comment: An emitter follower (a/k/a common collector) or source follower (a/k/a common drain) amplifier will amplify current but not voltage. However, when operated in class A (no saturation and no cut-off), they waste a great deal of power, especially when idle. To remove this inefficiency, they are typically implemented as push-pull amplifiers in class AB (without crossover distortion) or class B (with cross-over distortion). I will add a class AB push pull amplifier schematic to my answer.